# Lipschitz condition and uniform continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I know that a function is said to satisfy a Lipschitz condition on a domain $D$ if there exists a constant $K$ such that for all $x, y \in D,|f(x)-f(y)| \leq K|x-y|$. I am having trouble proving that if $f$ satisfics a Lipschitz condition on $D$, then it is uniformly continuous on $D .$

Comment: You can write an explicit formula for the $\delta$ given an $\epsilon$. Try it.

Comment: I want to give you a hint but believe me hint will be the solution. So, it's better to try by yourself.

Comment: You would like $K|x-y|<\varepsilon $ so you should choose $y$ near enogh $x$. Try to find by yourself how near you should choose $y$ and try to convince yourself that this "nearness" is uniform(it doesn't depend on the choice of $x$).